# Recursive inversion of singly linked list

Tags: recursion, linked-list

I've got the following short code, which is a solution to a problem of inverting a linked list.

```
void backwardslist(atom** head) {
atom* first;
atom* second;

if (*head == NULL) return; //if list is empty

first = *head;
second = first->next; // intuitive

if (second == NULL) return; 

backwardslist(&second); // recursive call with 2nd one as head, after we got variables
                     first and second

first->next->next = first; // when we get to the end, we rearrange it
first->next = NULL; // so last one is pointing to first, first is pointing to NULL

*head = second; // I dont understand this part, so the head is changing from the last, 
                   to the second element as the recursion goes to the beginning or am i 
                   missing something?
```

}

isn't the second=(pointer to the second of two pointers in the recursion)?

so the first time, i understand, it should point to the last one,

but as the recursion builds back, its constantly changing *head to second.

What's in the second atm that's being used?

Thank you guys

Comment: the principle of recursion is: 
-It works for the empty list and the list with 1 element
-The first element become the last
-I call my function on the rest of the list

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer that comes to mind is to recursively call your function until the end is reached. Then return the last node. When the recursive function returns, set the next pointer of the node returned to the head node.

```
  1) A->B->C->D
    2) A->B->C->D->C
    3)  A->B->C->D->C->B
    4)  A->B->C->D->C->B->A
    5)           D->C->B->A->Null
```

Answer (score 0):

`void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;`

```
/* empty list */
if (*head_ref == NULL)
   return;  

/* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
first = *head_ref; 
rest  = first->next;

/* List has only one node */
if (rest == NULL)
   return;  

/* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
recursiveReverse(&rest);
first->next->next  = first; 

/* tricky step -- see the diagram */
first->next  = NULL;         

/* fix the head pointer */
*head_ref = rest;
```

`}`